# How to compare and replace fields using awk

Tags: linux, awk

I have a two files. If Field-9 of File-1 and Field-1 of File-2 is same then replace  Field-1  of File-1 with Field-2 of File-1

file1:

```
12345||||||756432101000||756432||||
aaaaa||||||986754812345||986754||||
ccccc||||||134567222222||134567||||
```

file2:

```
756432|AAAAAAAAAAA  
986754|20030040000
```

The expected output is:

```
12345||||||AAAAAAAAAAA||756432||||
aaaaa||||||20030040000||986754||||
ccccc||||||134567222222||134567|||
```

I tried this code

```
awk -F"|" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2} NR>FNR{$7=a[$2];print}' OFS='|'  file2 file1
```

but instead of replacing the field, it gets deleted.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong column as the index of the array in the second block, and you are not checking for missing keys. This produces the output you posted:

```
awk -F '|' -v OFS='|' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}$9 in a{$7=a[$9]}1' file2 file1
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Could you please explain a[$9]!=""

Comment: @SGS: Sure, with `a[$9]!=""` we test if array `a` contains a value for the string that is represented in field `$9`, so we only change the value of `$7` when the corresponding value is found in file2.

Comment: Instead of `a[$9]!=""` you might consider `$9 in a`. With the former, awk will actually add an array element with `$9` as an index and an empty value. The latter just checks to see if it's there without using any extra memory. Usually it's fine either way but good to keep the difference in mind when there are huge files involved.

Comment: When you have 2 variables that must both have the same value, init them together to that value once instead of initing them to that same value in 2 separate locations to remove redundancy and improve clarity. So,in this case use `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} ...'` instead of `awk -F '|' -v OFS='|' '...'`